# Does not match the format HH:mm:ss

Tags: php, laravel

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/someurl',
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    data: {
        duration: $('input[name="duration"]').val(),
    }, error: function (response) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
        for (var key in json) {
            console.log(json['key']);
        }
    }
});
```

Inputs are like:

```
08:00:00 
or
19:00:00
or
20:05:01
```

This is my validator:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'duration' => 'required|date_format:"HH:mm:ss"',
]);
```

**Error:**

> The duration does not match the format HH:mm:ss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is wrong.

`HH:mm:ss` = HourHour:MonthMonth:SecondSecond

Correct is `H:i:s`

A case of [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)